# BizTalk 2013 r2 Administration Console fail to open after MS security update KB4338815

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Please help me finding a solution to these errors i'm getting wehen open **BizTalk Administration Console** after updating to **MS security update KB4338815**:

**First error:**

> Failed to load Group [xxxxxx:BizTalkMgmtDb] data providers. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)

[image]

> Failed to load Group [xxxxxx:BizTalkMgmtDb] data providers. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)

---

> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=47400&ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server+2013+R2&ProdVer=3.11.158.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.Properties.Errors&EvtID=FailedLoadingGroupProviders&EvtChain=Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.Properties.Errors+%2cFailedLoadingGroupProviders%3bBTSAdminMsg+%2c9218

===================================

> Failed to load Group [PLYSDEVBAL07:BizTalkMgmtDb] data providers. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)

---

> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=47400&ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server+2013+R2&ProdVer=3.11.158.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.Properties.Errors&EvtID=FailedLoadingGroupProviders&EvtChain=BTSAdminMsg+%2c9218

===================================

> An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons. (WinMgmt)

---

> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=47400&ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server+2013+R2&ProdVer=3.11.158.0&EvtSrc=BTSAdminMsg&EvtID=9218

---

> Program Location:
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>     at System.Management.ManagementObject.Get()
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.SnapIn.Framework.WmiProvider.SelectInstance(String className, String keyClause, Object[] keyValues)
>     at Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.GroupNode.ConnectToProviders()

**Second error:**

> Failed to create a BizTalkDBVersion COM component installed with a BizTalk server.
>   Class not registered (WinMgmt)

---

> Program Location:
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>     at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()
>     at Microsoft.BizTalk.SnapIn.Framework.WmiProvider.SelectWhere(String className, String condition)
>     at Microsoft.BizTalk.SnapIn.Framework.WmiProvider.SelectRemote(String className, String whereClause)
>     at Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.Nodes.AdaptersFolder.get_Adapters()
>     at Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.Nodes.AdaptersFolder.RefreshChildren()

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For our environment Windows 2012 R2 & BizTalk 2013 R2:

After lot of trial and errors, uninstalling  KB4338605 & KB4338419 patches resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Removing KB4338419 resolved my issues (Windows Server 2012 r2).

Technet: [Microsoft Security Updates cause BizTalk Admin Console errors: An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons (WinMgmt)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d08c395-1550-4171-8c03-23e1d2a9afbc/microsoft-security-updates-cause-biztalk-admin-console-errors-an-internal-failure-occurred-for?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Comment: Which KB to remove depends on the Server version and the particular version of .Net that a version of BizTalk uses.  That Technet thread has listed a few.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply and Nice to hear that ms working on a fix for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In our environment of BizTalk 2013 R2, `KB4340005` was installed as .NET update. So as per suggestions we wanted to uninstall the KB but while we checked the installed updates, We're unable to see the installed update for .NET turns out it was installed in another package. So We're unable to unistall the `KB4340005`.

So we did a workaround as suggested by Microsoft .  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345913

We added the Network Service account to local administrator Group.